# When use php 7.1 with Laravel Valet 2.7.0 got an error

Tags: php, laravel

I need to use php 7.1 with laravel valet, but after `valet use php@7.1` valet show error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input::getArgument($name) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface::getArgument(string $name) in /Users/slon/.composer/vendor/symfony/console/Input/Input.php on line 28
```

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2019 14:00:51) ( NTS )
```

```
composer global update
Nothing to install or update
```

Any ideas?

Comment: laravel 6 is not compatible with php 7.1, if you are using php 7.1, you need to run laravel 5.x, check what version of laravel you are using, that could be the isse

Comment: @Nathanael it's not depended on the project. Problem was in Valet level not at project. But project for which I need php 7.1 has Laravel 5.2